# PowerShell variables and C#

Tags: c#, variables, powershell, office365

I'm working on Office 365 plugin in C# and trying this PowerShell command:

```
$newLicense = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId example:ENTERPRISEPACK -DisabledPlans SHAREPOINTWAC,MCOSTANDARD,SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName test@example.com -AddLicenses "example:ENTERPRISEPACK" -LicenseOptions $newLicense
```

In PS, this works well. In C#, I'm having trouble to run this command.
Here is my C# code, from [PowerShellInvoker](http://pastebin.com/Gqd9nMw1) class:

```
var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ImportPSModule(new[] { MsOnline });
iss.ThrowOnRunspaceOpenError = true;
_runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
_runspace.Open();
_invoker = new RunspaceInvoke(_runspace);
```

I've tried many ways:

```
scriptText_ = "$newLicense = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId {1} -DisabledPlans SHAREPOINTWAC,MCOSTANDARD,SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE\n"+
"Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName test@example.com -AddLicenses \"example:ENTERPRISEPACK\" -LicenseOptions $newLicense");
```

I use this following method to execute other commands which works perfectly:

```
_invoker.Invoke(scriptText_);
```

And also:

```
var pipeline = _runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText_);
return pipeline.Invoke(); // and getting back the variable
```

I also tried to add the variable in the Runspace object:

```
_runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable ("newLicense", pipeline.Invoke());
```

But the command do not work, and returns no error.
I don't really understand the PowerShell environment (I'm a beginner in this).

Thanks in advance for all the help you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried just writing the variables to the output of the PowerShell commands and then reading the output of the `Invoke`? (This should help you identify if the variables are getting into the script.)

Comment: To the output of the PS commands ? May you be clearer ? I've tried to get the PSObject from the command without variable and it works. I have my "LicenseOption" object. So I tried to add it as a parameter, directly, like that: `var cmd = new Command("New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId example:ENTERPRISEPACK -DisabledPlans SHAREPOINTWAC,MCOSTANDARD,SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE", true); cmd.Parameters.Add(variableName_, variableValue_); pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd); var result = pipeline.Invoke();` and it fails. I really don't understand how C# correctly deals with variables (and parameters btw).

Comment: I mean just put `$myVariable` in the invoked command and check the right value comes back (ie. confirm that the `SetVariable` is working. Debugging: when stuck either your tools are limited *or you're assuming something is working when it isn't* and the latter is most likely.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you are encountering an error that the PowerShell engine isn't showing you.  Try this approach instead to observe non-terminating errors:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(@"Get-ChildItem c:\xyzzy");
var results = ps.Invoke();
if (ps.HadErrors)
{
    foreach (var errorRecord in ps.Streams.Error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(errorRecord);
    }
}
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```